# Set of points that satisfy the sum of the distances between a point P and points A(-2,0) and B(2,0) = 7

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, plane-geometry

So, I have to find the set of points whose distance to point $A(-2, 0)$ plus the distance to point $B(2, 0)$ is equal to $7$.

I am solving it this way:

$ d(P, A) + d(P, B) = 7  \Leftrightarrow $

$ \sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}=7 \Leftrightarrow $

$ (x+2)^2+y^2+(x-2)^2+y^2=49 \Leftrightarrow $

$ x^2+4x+4+y^2+x^2-4x+4+y^2=49 \Leftrightarrow $

$ 2x^2+2y^2=49-8 \Leftrightarrow $

$x^2+y^2=\frac{41}{2} $

So, we have a circle centered in the Origin and radius $\sqrt{\frac{41}{2}}$

Now, when I drew this circle, and measured the distance from any point belonging to the circle to A adding to the distance of that same point to B, I get the result of around $9$

And effectively, $2\sqrt{\frac{41}{2}} \approx 9.05$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $ \sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}=7 \Leftrightarrow (x+2)^2+y^2+(x-2)^2+y^2=49$ is the wrong step: you are not squaring both sides correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you expand $(a+b)^2$, you get $\color{blue}{\text{cross terms}}$ also as
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+\color{blue}{2ab}$$

You have missed
$$(x+2)^2+y^2+(x-2)^2+y^2+\color{blue}{2\cdot \sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}\cdot\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}}=49$$

One more squaring will clear the square roots and finally give correct equation (of an ellipse).

If this is tedious, one can recognize the curve with given property of constant sum of distances from two points as an ellipse. And try to find its parameters.

The ellipse will be centered at midpoint of two foci, $(0,0)$. Major axis $2a=7 \Rightarrow a^2=49/4$. Distance of center from foci, $ae=2$. Minor axis is $2b$ where $b^2=a^2-a^2e^2=33/4$. Therefore required ellipse is
$$\frac{4x^2}{49}+\frac{4y^2}{33}=1$$

Comment: Oh, I don't know that cross term rule.. It's been 12 years since I've done maths. Do you have an explicit article or website where I can review this rule that I forgot?

Comment: @msmilkshake See for example [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/applying-the-perfect-square-identity/).

Comment: Thanks! Appreciated.

Comment: @msmilkshake It would also be good to review other facts from basic algebra that you may have forgotten. They're likely to be relevant to other questions like this one.